# Storing constructor with parameters in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have two classes. The idea is to create alarms and store them in an array to later display them in a JTable. Im stuck when I create an alarm and I want to store it in Arrays. I need help adding them to an array with all its parameters.

```
public class AlarmTester {

static ArrayList<Alarm> arr = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
public static void main(String[] args) {


  DateFormat todaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    long milis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Alarm a1 = new Alarm("Test", 700000, null, null, null, 0);
    Alarm a2 = new Alarm("Test2", System.currentTimeMillis(), null, null, null, 0);     


}

}
```

Here are the methods

```
public class Alarm {
private String description;
private Calendar  endDay ,startTime, endTime;
private long startDay;
private int interval;

public Alarm(String d, long sd, Calendar ed ,Calendar st, Calendar et, int ri){
    description = d;
    startDay= sd; 
    endDay= ed;
    startTime= st;
    endTime = et;
    interval= ri;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public long getStartDay(){
    return startDay;
}

public Calendar getEndDay(){
    return endDay;
}

public Calendar getStartTime(){
    return startTime;
}

public Calendar getEndTime(){
    return endTime;
}

public int getInterval(){
    return interval;
}


// this method are for editing alarm

public void setDescription(String d){
    description= d;
}

public void setStartDay(long sd){
    startDay=sd;
}

public void setEndDay(Calendar ed){
    endDay=ed;
}

public void setStartTime(Calendar st){
    startTime=st; 
}

public void setEndTime(Calendar et){
    endTime=et;
}

public void setInterval(int ri){
    interval=ri;
}
}
```

And the tester

Comment: Now, what is your question?

Comment: `arr.add(a1); arr.add(a2);` - read javadoc than ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Alarm[] alarms = new Alarm[] {a1,a2};
```

This makes an *Alarm* array and adds the 2 *Alarms*,